# Download the file mvc2 using actionlink

Tags: file-upload, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to upload and download the resume using asp.net mvc2. I already created the codings. It is uploaded successfully. When I try to download the file I have an issue..
It is showing a empty page..

**Controller:**

```
 [HandleErrorWithAjaxFilter]
    public ActionResult UploadResume(HttpPostedFileBase FileData)
    {
        Stream fromStream = FileData.InputStream;
        Stream toStream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Resumes/") + FileData.FileName, FileMode.Create);

        LoggedInCandidate.ResumeFileName = FileData.FileName;
        //_repository.Save();
        _userRepository.Save();

        return Json(new JsonActionResult
        {
            Success = true,
            Message = "Resume has been uploaded."
        });
        //return Json("Resume has been uploaded.");
    }
```

**View:**

```
    <input id="Resume" type="file" name="Resume" />
```

**Download:**

```
<p>
                <% var link = Url.Content("~/Content/Resumes/") + Model.ResumeFileName; %>
                <a href="<%: link %>">Download Resume</a> 
            </p>
```

when I click the link download resume, it shows the name of the file at url but it is not downloading.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Controller:**

```
 [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Download(string fileName)
    {
        string pfn = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Resumes/" + fileName);

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(pfn))
        {
            //throw new ArgumentException("Invalid file name or file not exists!");

            return Json(new JsonActionResult { Success = false, Message = "Invalid file name or file not exists!" });
        }
        else
        {

            return new BinaryContentResult()
            {
                FileName = fileName,
                ContentType = "application/octet-stream",
                Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pfn)
            };
        }

    }
```

**Model:**/BinaryFileResult

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

namespace Dial4Jobz.Models
{
    public class BinaryContentResult : ActionResult
    {

```
    public BinaryContentResult()
    {
    }

    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {

        context.HttpContext.Response.ClearContent();
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = ContentType;

        context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",

        "attachment; filename=" + FileName);

        context.HttpContext.Response.BinaryWrite(Content);
        context.HttpContext.Response.End();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you should do it. Create an Action in your Controller like this:

```
public FileResult Download(string fileName)
{
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Resumes/"), fileName);
    var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

    // Assuming that the resume is an MS Word document...
    return File(fileStream, "application/vnd.ms-word");
}
```

And, in your View, you'll have:

```
<p>
  <%: Html.ActionLink("Download Resume", "Download", new { fileName = Model.ResumeFileName }) %>
</p>
```

Comment: It is not downloading.. what will do? pls help me

Comment: What happens exactly? Do you get the FileStream object?

Comment: If i click the download link, showing empty page. i am using google chrome. no download option opening..

Comment: You didn't answer my second question. Do you get the FileStream object or is it null?

Comment: I get filestream object. but when i click the link it shows the current path in url & not downloading..this is the issue.